# How to change the file type in the dialog opened by OpenDialog

Tags: dm-script

Hi, all:

I'd like to choose a tif file in the dialog opened by OpenDialog command. But the default file type is dm files and so on. I need to change the file type to All files, then I can choose tif file. Is there any method to automatically do that?

[image]

Regards

Chen ZX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so straight forward and an undocumented/unsupported feature of GMS scripting. Try the following (provided a TIFF I/O Handler is available)

```c
{
    object file_filters = NewFileFilterList()
    
    // List of available IO Handlers
    object IOHandlers = ImageIO_GetImageIOHandlers( )
    forEach(object IOHandlerIter ; IOHandlers){
        Result("\n\n NAME      : "+IOHandlerIter.ImageIOHandler_GetHandlerName())
        Result("\n ID        : "+IOHandlerIter.ImageIOHandler_GetHandlerIdentifier())
        Result("\n FormatID  : "+IOHandlerIter.ImageIOHandler_GetFormatId())        
    }
    
    // Adding the TIF Handler's files to the filter
    object tiffHandler = ImageIO_GetImageIOHandlerByName("TIFF Format")
    if (tiffHandler.ScriptObjectIsValid()) 
        tiffHandler.ImageIOHandler_AddFileFilterToFileFilterList(file_filters)
    else
        Throw("TIFF IO-Handler not found")
    
    string ResultPath
    number Resultfilter
    number filter = 73      // Format ID of the handler
    string path = GetApplicationDirectory("open_save",0)
    
    if (!PoseGetFilePathForsaveDialog(ResultPath,ResultFilter, NULL , "Prompt", path,filter,file_filters ))
        Throw("Dialog cancelled.")
        
    Result("\n\n Chosen path: " + resultPath)
    Result("\n Chosen filter: " + resultfilter)
}
```

Comment: Great solution. Thx. One more question. This solution is to open a dialog with save button, and when I double click a tiff file, it will ask me whether I'd like to overwrite this file. Is that possible to make it a "open" button, while filter the tiff file?

Comment: @ChenZX there is also a PoseGetFilePathForOpenDialog(). However, I could not get it to work with customized filters unfortunately. I think this isn't supported on the GMS side.

Comment: I see. PoseGetFilePathForOpenDialog() is enough for me. Thanks. @BmyGuest